# Subscribe to a Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification in .NET 6 C# Backend Code

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an IoT project using Raspberry Pi which runs C# code written in .NET 6. I know we can subscribe to FCM notifications from android, iOS or javascript (web). But I want to subscribe/listen to firebase notifications directly in the C# backend code. Is it possible?
I have tried the 'FirebaseAdmin' NuGet package but I could not find in the documentation what I need.

Answer (score -2):

```
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationTokens = new List<string>()
{
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1",
    // ...
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n",
};
var message = new MulticastMessage()
{
    Tokens = registrationTokens,
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "score", "850" },
        { "time", "2:45" },
    },
};

var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message);
if (response.FailureCount > 0)
{
    var failedTokens = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < response.Responses.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!response.Responses[i].IsSuccess)
        {
            // The order of responses corresponds to the order of the registration tokens.
            failedTokens.Add(registrationTokens[i]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"List of tokens that caused failures: {failedTokens}");
}
```